# Switching between apps with URL Schemes (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm developing an iPhone app with Swift which acts on certain file types (.xml &.zip).  I've added these filetypes to the project file as a UTI (Uniform Type Identifiers).  When accessing these sorts of files, usually from my email, I press and hold the file and a menu pops up from below.  I choose my app icon that says "Open in MyApp".  Is there a way that I can return to the email which triggered this event from within the app?

I've done some research on this and found that URL Schemes are the best way for inter - app communication, but you cannot arbitrarily open an app just to open it.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

The vision I have in mind is sort of how Google apps communicate with each other.  For example, when opening a link from gmail, it switches apps to chrome. When chrome loads, the page back navigator is in Chrome displays the text similar to "back to gmail"

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9 the system implements this automatically, as seen in this screenshot [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%209%20proactive%20go%20back%20to%20previous%20app&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAmoVChMI8bLw2oWDxwIVQ5MNCh0usAAI#tbm=isch&q=ios9%20one%20tap%20app%20switching&imgrc=ZBTBXo51a_NBzM%3A).